# How to set a FONT in HTML

Tags: html

My font doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

I added the **google font** in the head.
Its below meta.

I also added the CSS code.

I hope someone can help me.

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}

body { 
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
}

h1 { text-align: center; }

.hoofdtabel { 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
} /* Vervangt cellspacing="0" */

.kop { 
 width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
 background-color:  #5570aa;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 72px; 
}
    
.menu { 
 width: 12%;
    height: 70%;
 padding: 5px;                   /* Vervangt cellpadding="5" */
 background-color: #9e6171;
 vertical-align: top; 
}

.inhoud { 
 width: 96%;
    height: 85%;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #b8c6c4;
 vertical-align: top; 
} 
     
.onder {
 width: 100%;
    height: 5%; 
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: right;
 color: white;
}

.button {
 padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #e9ece5;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #b3c2bf;
    width: 100px;

}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
}

.frame {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 border: none;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet"> 
<title>Hi</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Hi">

 <h1>Hi</h1>
<font size="4" >
 <p>Hello all<br>


</font> 



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey hey Thom, have you define it as a rule in your CSS for the `body` selector? Have a look at this [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) link from Google regarding fonts and CSS.

Comment: Oh I just saw your CSS snippet go up. So on the `body` selector you'll want to add `font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;`.

Comment: When you say 'your font does not work', do you mean a particular font or your text is not showing?

Answer (score 2):

You just loaded the font, but forgot to tell which element should use it.

Example to use it on all paragraphs (in CSS file):

```
p {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think your code should look something like this:

style.css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body { 
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

h1 { text-align: center; }

p {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

... and the rest of the file, which you posted
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<title>Hi</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Hi">

<h1>Hi</h1>
<font size="4">
 <p>Hello all<br><p>
</font>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After this, the **Hello all** text should use the Source Sans Pro font.

In addition, you forgot to link your CSS file in the HTML document (same method as you link the google font). See in my example below the google font.

Comment: This should work @Thom.  Personally, I would remove `p{font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif};` and place `font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;` within the `body{}` but that is just a matter of preference.

Comment: I just put that there to demonstrate different fonts can be appiled to different elements, not just the whole document only.